# Telegram bot in asp.net Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, bots, telegram, application-start

I write a telegrom bot with c# and put it in my asp.net web application . but does not work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace MyFirstBot
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    TelegramBotClient bot = new TelegramBotClient("My Token");

    TweetTestEntities context = new TweetTestEntities();

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
        bot.StartReceiving();
    }

    private void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
}
}
```

My application is on a host with no problem

Comment: why you not using `webHooks`?

Comment: **به زبون مادری** ظاهرا قراره بساط تلگرام رو تو ایران جمع کنن!. `بهتره` یه بازنگری بکنی

Comment: @PurTahan Because I dont have SSL

Comment: @PurTahan بیشتر برای تمرین و آشنایی با پیام رسان ها دارم انجام میدم . حالا میزنیم اگه فیلتر نشد چه بهتر :-)

Comment: You can use self-signed ssl certificate

Comment: @PurTahan Finally I create ssl with teletter.net . Can you Help me in webhook for asp.net web form ?

Comment: use [this](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/2287/~/adding-an-ssl-certificate-to-plesk-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use below Code to Initialize your Bot and WebHook

```
Public Shared Sub init()
    Client = New TelegramBotClient(tocken)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<Your Self-Signed SSL Key>))
    Dim cert As New FileToSend("SSL.pem", ms)
    Client.SetWebhookAsync("https://Your/WebHook", cert)

    With Client.GetMeAsync.Result
        BotID = .Id
        BotUserName = .Username
        Try
            BotPhotoID = Client.GetUserProfilePhotosAsync(.Id).Result.Photos.First.First.FileId
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Mark it as Solution, if it's Helped You

Comment: Thank you a lot . Should I use this in my Global.asax ?

Comment: Yes, In every were you know

Comment: Update your skills, if you want to continue programming with asp.net, Use Updated Method, Like Asp.Net WebPages Razor.